Movie about man's nose gone bananas
A short movie (USA, maybe 90s), about 30 minutes. What I remember from the plot — a man's nose goes wild at night, started living on its own, made hands take scissors and cut it off from man's nose.
It's was really funny and also scary for me, because I was a kid. I thought it was an episode of "Tales from the Crypt" but it looks like it's not (it's from the same years).

Country\language? Approximate year?

USA, maybe 90s?

And I'm assuming live-action (like Tales from the Crypt)?

The descriptions sounds like the Nikolai Gogol short story, The Nose.
Wikipedia lists one film adaptation, the pinscreen animation Le nez (1963),



There are other works credited to Gogol on imdb, some of which may be candidates.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0364548/
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076466/
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0172891/
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1505105/

No, sorry, for sure it's not that old, it was like  "Tales from the Crypt" and from the same years.

It's a part of the Quicksilver Highway movie. Adapted from the short story The Body Politic by Clive Barker.
